# Pure HTML5 Websocket Client for NodeJS NO JAVASCRIPT

Tags: node.js, html, google-chrome, websocket, socket.io

I am reading and seeing that all the major web browsers are removing javascript from their supported languages which I honestly believe is a HUGE and massive mistake as things like Socket.io and jquery are written in javascript and are just 2 of the biggest libraries used. So if javascript is being removed, what is there to replace it? How do I use something like socket.io without any javascript that will natively run in any web browser(hence HTML5)? Is there a getting started guide or reference that can help me get started with sockets in pure HTML5?(Already having issues on Google Chrome with my native javascript coding).

Comment: Where are you reading that web browsers are removing javascript? I highly doubt this is the case unless those browser vendors really wish to alienate a large portion of internet users....

Comment: https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml

Comment: That's about Java, *not* Java*Script*.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh *bangs head on wall*  so then why is   document.getElementById('success_msg').style="display: none"; not working in IE, Edge, or Chrome? Also, changing the innerHTML does not work either, yet it works perfectly in firefox.

Comment: That's an entirely different question that you should post separately.